# Form3 linked to Form2. Values not updating upon change

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am creating a windows forms app with 3 forms.
I am able to send values and update them timely between form1 and form2.
But i have problems with updating values from form3 to form2.

My code in form2 is as follows:
Public Sub GetValues_Form3()

```
    xlExcelLink = Form3.LoadProjDB()

    If xlExcelLink Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Projekt Datenbank fehlt." & vbNewLine & "Bitte wählen Sie in den Optionen erneut die Projektdatenbank aus.", , "Fehler")
        Form1.ib_OptionsTab_Click(Form1.ib_OptionsTab, Nothing) 'Opens Form3
    End If

End Sub
```

My code in Form 3 is as follows:

```
Private Sub ib_ProjDB_Browse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ib_ProjDB_Browse.Click

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        tb_Excel.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

End Sub

Function LoadProjDB() As String

    Dim Form3_ExcelPath As String = tb_Excel.Text
    MsgBox(Form3_ExcelPath)
    If Form3_ExcelPath IsNot Nothing And System.IO.File.Exists(Form3_ExcelPath) Then
        MsgBox(Form3_ExcelPath)
        Form2.Label1.Text = Form3_ExcelPath
        Return Form3_ExcelPath
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

I have a default file path. I check if the path exists.
If it doesnt exist, i want my form2 to open form3, where i can select the new file.

After form3 is closed, i get the path string from form3 in form2, and it checks if the string is nothing.
If it is nothing, it will open form3 again.

The problem here is:
I am able to select a new file and it is displaying correctly in form3.
But form2 is not updating its vale from form3.
It still has the first value that it got from form3.

Please help.
Thank you.

Edit1:

Now I am trying to run Subs and Function in Form2 from Form1.
It seems the variables are changing temporarily when executed, but the functions are not being triggered by my action.

I cant seem to find a solution for it till now.

Edit 2:
@Idle_Mind

Im using a public sub which handles button click in form1 to display form3.

```
Public Sub ib_OptionsTab_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ib_OptionsTab.Click

    If ib_OptionsTab.Tag = 0 Then
        Form3_in_Panel()
    ElseIf ib_OptionsTab.Tag = 1 Then
        Form3_Out_Panel()
    End If

End Sub
```

Form3 is the oped using this function in form1.

```
Function Form3_in_Panel()

    If Form3_Load = True Then
        Dim f3 As New Form3
        f3.TopLevel = False
        f3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        pnl_Fill.Controls.Add(f3)
        f3.Visible = True
        f3.BringToFront()
        Form3_Load = False
        frm3 = pnl_Fill.Controls.Item("Form3")
    Else
        pnl_Fill.Controls.Item("Form3").Visible = True
    End If
    ib_OptionsTab.Tag = 1

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You have `Form3.LoadProjDB()` which runs `LoadProjDB()` in the DEFAULT INSTANCE of Form3.  Most likely this is not the same instance of Form3 that was displayed on the screen.  How did you display Form3?  I'm guessing you created a new instance with the `new` keyword?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I created Form3 using Form1. When xlExcelLink Is Nothing, then it just makes form3 visible. Both Form2 and Form3 are displayed actually inside a panel in Form1.

Since i need my values entered in both form2 and form3 to be retained, i chose to make them visible and invisible, rather than disposing them based on the requirement.

Is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: But HOW are you displaying Form3?  Show us that little snippet.

Comment: please check my edit above @Idle_Mind

Comment: There it is.  Like I said, previously: `Dim f3 As New Form3`  Here you're creating a NEW INSTANCE of Form3 and displaying that in the Panel.  But in other parts of the code you're accessing Form3 with `Form3.LoadProjDB()`, which is using the DEFAULT INSTANCE.  These two instances are not the same form; you are working with two different copies of Form3.

Comment: You need to reference the actual instance of Form3 that is being displayed in your panel.  Either keep that reference by moving the declaration from local to Form level, or access the actual instance using the reference directly contained within the Panel (casting it as necessary).

Comment: @Idle_Mind i am using a variable "Form3_Load". When the app is run, Form3_Load has a default value of True. Once Form3 is loaded, it gets changed to False. After every time im accesing form3, i just make my form3 visible or invisible, if Form3_Load is false.

Comment: Please read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html)...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks a lot for the info.
I was using f2 and f3 as new instances of Form2 and Form3 to create and add them in form1 respectively. But trying to access eachother using Form2 and Form3, instead of f2 and f3. So now after reading your info, i created f2 and f3 as new forms, but added the default instance of Form2 and Form3 in a panel of Fprm1. Now they communicate with each other.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Even so, i dont even need to create f2 and f3 instances. Simply by using default instance, i was able to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Right, either use all default instances or not.  Just pick one method and go with it.  As long as you understand the difference you should be fine.